# How to run 2 commands in same line in SROS?

Tags: command, nokia

How to run 2 commands in same line in SROS? I have tried

1. command1 & command2

   2. command1 && command2
   3. command1 | command2
   4. command1 || command2
   5. command1; command2
   6. (command1 &) & (command2 &)
   7. (command1; command2) &
   8. (command1 &) && (command2 &)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's possible, at least not with the version(s) I'm currently running.  Depending on your requirements you can load your commands into a configuration file and execute it from CLI as a single entry.  For example if you wanted to show the FDB of two VPLSs in a single operation you could add those show commands to a file called **show.cfg** on CF3 and then execute it with `exec cf3:\show.cfg`.

```
A:7705-299# file type cf3:\show.cfg 
File: show.cfg
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
show service id 7299 fdb detail
show service id 13002297 fdb detail

===============================================================================

A:7705-299# exec cf3:\show.cfg 

===============================================================================
Forwarding Database, Service 7299
===============================================================================
ServId    MAC               Source-Identifier        Type     Last Change
                                                     Age      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7299      01:0b:20:0b:ca:d7 sap:1/1/10               L/44     03/29/20 11:23:34
7299      30:c8:98:c6:b5:47 sdp:11:7299              L/456    01/16/20 15:02:17
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No. of MAC Entries: 2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Legend:  L=Learned O=Oam P=Protected-MAC C=Conditional S=Static
===============================================================================

===============================================================================
Forwarding Database, Service 13002297
===============================================================================
ServId    MAC               Source-Identifier        Type     Last Change
                                                     Age      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
13002297  0a:b0:02:cf:5a:f0 sap:1/1/7:200            L/117    04/09/20 11:11:20
13002297  11:a2:a8:c6:b5:47 sdp:11:13002297          L/396    02/13/20 11:13:11
13002297  3d:d0:4b:25:5c:fc sap:1/1/12               L/44     04/21/20 00:59:03
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No. of MAC Entries: 3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Legend:  L=Learned O=Oam P=Protected-MAC C=Conditional S=Static
===============================================================================
Executed 2 lines in 0.8 seconds from file cf3:\show.cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

I also don't think it is possible to send two commands in a single line. However, I have an another workaround for you if you are using SecureCRT.
In SecureCRT, there is an option to send multiple commands in one click. I have used to send following commands in one click, please see following:

```
environment no more
show version
show chassis
```

To do this, I have opened "Button Bar" under "View" section first:

[image]

Then, it gives me a button as following:

[image]

When you right click the green button, and click on edit, you will receive following screen. You can type any command as following, and you can also change the button color.

[image]

So that you can run multiple commands in one click.